# python: append a list of values into a list

Tags: python, list, csv

```
c1=[]
      for row in c:
        c1.append(row[0:13])
```

c is a variable containing a csv file

i am going through every row in it and i want only the first 14 elements to be in the `c1`

what am i doing wrong?

Comment: It's not really clear what you want to do, or what you think is going wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nicer:

```
c1= [row[:13] for row in c.readlines()]
```

if that doesn't work, you may not assigning to c properly.

Also keep in mind that if you want first 14 characters, you actually want to do row[:14]
Then you get characters 0->13 inclusively, or 14 total.

Comment: thank you very much, actually it's not characters it is a list

Answer (score 2):

That will not include the element indexed at [13].

```
c1=[]
  for row in c:
    c1.append(row[:14])
```

If you want the individual elements (the above code will append a list, much like a 2D array) you should append it in the following way:

```
    c1 += row[:14]
```